# how to resolve gnome-software full package name search bug (ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: gnome-software

For example, a partial text search will find the Spotify flatpak, but a full text search will only show the snap.  (I know there are many complaints about gnome-software, but I've never seen this specific bug described.)

[image: snap only displayed with full name search]

[image: both snap and flatpak displayed with partial name search]

Comment: Please review the existing bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/ . If this bug has already been reported, please mark that the bug affects you. Even better, if you're willing to help troubleshoot, patch, and/or test, then subscribe to the bug. You can see that the developers welcome help! If the bug has not already been reported, then please report it.

Comment: Couldn't find any existing bugs, but I already switched to PopOS, which doesn't seem to have the issue, so I can't troubleshoot or help fix anymore.